# Symfony 2 multiple upload

Tags: php, symfony, upload

using symfony 2.5 and Php 5.3.13.

i just want to add a field file type with option multiple => true.

It works ! but when the user click a second time on the button [Upload] it's deleting the first one already uploaded..

How can i do something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/gxfwvtqe/

In a symfony way, AdvertType.php  :

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title',     'text')
        ->add('content',   'textarea')
        ->add('category',  'choice', array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'incident' => 'Incident',
                'general'  => 'General',
            ),
            'multiple'  => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'required'  => true,))
        ->add('documents','file', array(
            'required' => false,
            'data_class'=> null,
            'multiple' => true))
        ->add('save', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

form.html.twig :

```
<div class="well">
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': ''}}) }}

{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.documents) }}

{{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}

{{ form_rest(form) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```